# Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void CommentRequiredOnRejection(Map<Id,SObject>) from the type AP03_CommentRequiredOnRejection

Tags: apex

```
public class AP03_CommentRequiredOnRejection {
public static void CommentRequiredOnRejection(Map <Id,case >newMap) {
    Map<Id,case >rejectedStatements = new Map<Id,case>{};

    for (case cas:newMap.values()) {
        /* 
          Get the old object record, and check if the approval status 
          field has been updated to rejected. If so, put it in a map 
          so we only have to use 1 SOQL query to do all checks.
        */
        case oldcas = (case) Trigger.oldMap.get(cas.Id);

        if (oldcas.Status != 'Rejected' && cas.Status == 'Rejected') {
            rejectedStatements.put(cas.Id, cas);
        }
    }

    if (!rejectedStatements.isEmpty()) {
        // UPDATE 2/1/2014: Get the most recent approval process instance for the object.
        // If there are some approvals to be reviewed for approval, then
        // get the most recent process instance for each object.
        List < Id > processInstanceIds = new List < Id > {};

        for (case cs:[SELECT(SELECT ID FROM ProcessInstances ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1)  FROM case WHERE ID IN:                         rejectedStatements.keySet()]) {
            processInstanceIds.add(cs.ProcessInstances[0].Id);
        }

        // Now that we have the most recent process instances, we can check
        // the most recent process steps for comments.  
        for (ProcessInstance pi: [SELECT TargetObjectId,
                (SELECT Id, StepStatus, Comments FROM Steps ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1)
                FROM ProcessInstance
                WHERE Id IN: processInstanceIds
                ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
            ]) {
            if ((pi.Steps[0].Comments == null ||
                    pi.Steps[0].Comments.trim().length() == 0)) {
                rejectedStatements.get(pi.TargetObjectId).addError(
                    'Operation Cancelled: Please provide a rejection reason!');
            }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Handler:

```
/*Method Added to Assign Old Owner ID*/
protected override void beforeUpdate() {
    if (PAD.canTrigger(PAD.AP03_CommentRequiredOnRejection)) {

        AP03_CommentRequiredOnRejection.CommentRequiredOnRejection(trigger.newMap);
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure have save saved `AP03_CommentRequiredOnRejection` class? Is the newMap, a map of cases?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a trigger on Case which calls `beforeUpdate()` in your Handler class. Then, from the Handler, you try to call `AP03_CommentRequiredOnRejection.CommentRequiredOnRejection(trigger.newMap);`

The method you want to call is defined as

```
CommentRequiredOnRejection(Map <Id,case >newMap)
```

It expects one argument of the type `Map<Id, Case>`, but the actual call goes out to a method with an argument of type `Map<Id, SObject>`.

In the context of a trigger `Trigger.newMap` is a Map containing IDs and the SObject type your trigger is on. So if you have a trigger on Case, within that trigger Trigger.newMap is of Id, Case. But outside of the trigger - in your Handler - Trigger.newMap is of the generic type Id, SObject.

Either change the signature of `CommentRequiredOnRejection`to require a `Map<Id, SObject>` - and cast the contained data to Case - or pass Trigger.newMap as `Map<Id, Case>` from your trigger to your Handler.

Also refer to [Convert Trigger into Apex Class](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/274544/convert-trigger-into-apex-class/274546#274546)